# Different find results between cakephp 2.5 and 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am migrating my app from cakephp 2.5 to 3.0 and I am doing a `->find()` method and then looping over the results in the controller. However I am getting different results returned in 3.0. I seem to be getting the query settings that cakephp uses before going to the database rather than the results.

EmployeesController.php

2.5 Code:

```
//Open courses
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Employee.id' => 1, 'CoursesEmployee.completed' => false),
    'limit' => 3
    );
$recentOpen = $this->CoursesEmployee->find('all', $options);
debug($recentOpen);

// get next module for each open course
foreach ($recentOpen as $key => &$value) {
    //do something
}
```

and the results:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'CoursesEmployee' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'employee_id' => '1',
        'course_id' => '1',
        'course_module_id' => '5',
        'progress' => '10',
        'modified' => '2014-12-16 22:40:42',
        'created' => '2014-11-18 00:00:00',
        'completed' => false
    ),
    'Employee' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'hotel_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Keith Power',
        'email' => '',
        'surname' => 'Power',
        'employee_num' => '',
        'modified' => '2014-11-19 12:52:36',
        'created' => '2014-11-18 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Course' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Manual Handling Training',
        'course_lenght' => '02:12:00'
    ),
    'CourseModule' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'course_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Module 5',
        'type' => 'video',
        'video_url' => '',
        'video_lenght' => '00:00:00'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'CoursesEmployee' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'employee_id' => '1',
        'course_id' => '2',
        'course_module_id' => '5',
        'progress' => '100',
        'modified' => '2014-12-05 15:13:47',
        'created' => '2014-11-20 00:00:00',
        'completed' => false
    ),
    'Employee' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'hotel_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Keith Power',
        'email' => '',
        'surname' => 'Power',
        'employee_num' => '',
        'modified' => '2014-11-19 12:52:36',
        'created' => '2014-11-18 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Course' => array(
        'id' => null,
        'name' => null,
        'course_lenght' => null
    ),
    'CourseModule' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'course_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Module 5',
        'type' => 'video',
        'video_url' => '',
        'video_lenght' => '00:00:00'
    )
  )
)
```

3.0 Code:

```
$this->loadModel('CoursesEmployees');

//Open courses
$options = [
    'conditions' => ['Employees.id' => 1, 'CoursesEmployees.completed' => false],
    'limit' => 3,
    'contain' => 'Employees'
];
$recentOpen = $this->CoursesEmployees->find('all', $options)->toArray();

debug($recentOpen);
```

But I do not get results returned expected, the actual values seem contained inside an array called `properties` there is no mention the in cake book about accessing properties:

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\CoursesEmployee) {

    'new' => false,
    'accessible' => [
        'employee_id' => true,
        'course_id' => true,
        'course_module_id' => true,
        'progress' => true,
        'completed' => true,
        'employee' => true,
        'course' => true,
        'course_module' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'employee_id' => (int) 1,
        'course_id' => (int) 1,
        'course_module_id' => (int) 5,
        'progress' => (int) 10,
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

            'time' => '2014-12-16T22:40:42+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

            'time' => '2014-11-18T00:00:00+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'completed' => false,
        'employee' => object(App\Model\Entity\Employee) {

            'new' => false,
            'accessible' => [
                'user_id' => true,
                'hotel_id' => true,
                'name' => true,
                'email' => true,
                'surname' => true,
                'employee_num' => true,
                'hotel' => true,
                'courses' => true
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'id' => (int) 1,
                'user_id' => (int) 1,
                'hotel_id' => (int) 1,
                'name' => 'Keith Power',
                'email' => '',
                'surname' => 'Power',
                'employee_num' => '',
                'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                    'time' => '2014-11-19T12:52:36+0000',
                    'timezone' => 'UTC',
                    'fixedNowTime' => false

                },
                'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                    'time' => '2014-11-18T00:00:00+0000',
                    'timezone' => 'UTC',
                    'fixedNowTime' => false

                }
            ],
            'dirty' => [],
            'original' => [],
            'virtual' => [],
            'errors' => [],
            'repository' => 'Employees'

        }
    ],
    'dirty' => [],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
    'repository' => 'CoursesEmployees'

},
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\CoursesEmployee) {

    'new' => false,
    'accessible' => [
        'employee_id' => true,
        'course_id' => true,
        'course_module_id' => true,
        'progress' => true,
        'completed' => true,
        'employee' => true,
        'course' => true,
        'course_module' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'id' => (int) 3,
        'employee_id' => (int) 1,
        'course_id' => (int) 2,
        'course_module_id' => (int) 5,
        'progress' => (int) 100,
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

            'time' => '2014-12-05T15:13:47+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

            'time' => '2014-11-20T00:00:00+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'completed' => false,
        'employee' => object(App\Model\Entity\Employee) {

            'new' => false,
            'accessible' => [
                'user_id' => true,
                'hotel_id' => true,
                'name' => true,
                'email' => true,
                'surname' => true,
                'employee_num' => true,
                'hotel' => true,
                'courses' => true
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'id' => (int) 1,
                'user_id' => (int) 1,
                'hotel_id' => (int) 1,
                'name' => 'Keith Power',
                'email' => '',
                'surname' => 'Power',
                'employee_num' => '',
                'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                    'time' => '2014-11-19T12:52:36+0000',
                    'timezone' => 'UTC',
                    'fixedNowTime' => false

                },
                'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                    'time' => '2014-11-18T00:00:00+0000',
                    'timezone' => 'UTC',
                    'fixedNowTime' => false

                }
            ],
            'dirty' => [],
            'original' => [],
            'virtual' => [],
            'errors' => [],
            'repository' => 'Employees'

        }
    ],
    'dirty' => [],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
    'repository' => 'CoursesEmployees'

}
]
```

Is there another step required in 3.0. It is finding the two records in both, but the format of 3.0 is so different I don't know how to access the values like I did in 2.5 to do my loop.

*****Update

As suggested I have updated to Cakephp 3.05. Now all the extra properties are hidden and I am left with the results in object form. I am using `->toArray()` but it does not seem to change the object.

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\CoursesEmployee) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'employee_id' => (int) 1,
    'course_id' => (int) 1,
    'course_module_id' => (int) 5,
    'progress' => (int) 10,
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2014-12-16T22:40:42+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2014-11-18T00:00:00+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'completed' => false,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'employee_id' => true,
        'course_id' => true,
        'course_module_id' => true,
        'progress' => true,
        'completed' => true,
        'employee' => true,
        'course' => true,
        'course_module' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'CoursesEmployees'

},
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\CoursesEmployee) {

    'id' => (int) 2,
    'employee_id' => (int) 1,
    'course_id' => (int) 3,
    'course_module_id' => (int) 8,
    'progress' => (int) 100,
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2014-12-08T00:07:18+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2014-11-20T00:00:00+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'completed' => true,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'employee_id' => true,
        'course_id' => true,
        'course_module_id' => true,
        'progress' => true,
        'completed' => true,
        'employee' => true,
        'course' => true,
        'course_module' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'CoursesEmployees'

}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at custom formatted debug output, not a logical representation of the object (use for example `var_dump()` to see the difference).

Until recently, when dumping an entity via `debug()`, various hidden properties were being made visible, including the `$_properties` property, which holds a map of the available properties and their values.

The fact that you're seeing this, means that your codebase is outdated, you should update it to see the new format, where the properties are no longer being shown nested anymore, and "special" stuff is being shown as `[name]`: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/6564**

In any case, just access the properties as described in the Cookbook and everything's fine.

```
$recentOpen[0]->employee->name
```

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Accessing Entity Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data)**

Comment: Thanks, I have updated cakephp and I am left with the results now in object form. I have read over Cookbook but I am still confused how I would you the `$entity->` I have tried to replace the `$this->` but that is not the way to use it I am sure.

Comment: @KeithPower Sorry, but I don't really understand your problem. Just use your `$recentOpen` variable, iterate over it, or access the entity objects directly via their index in the array, or... I've updated the example.

Comment: Perfect, I was still thinking of it as an array rather than accessing it as an object `->` I can iterate over the results now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.5 code your condition is `Employee.id => 1`, whereas your condition in 3.0 query is `Employees.user_id => 1`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have added the auth in 3.0 so I changed to using user_id. I have updated the code to eliminate confusion. The result is the same.